# Conditional Pagination on Datatable

Tags: primefaces

I need conditional pagination on data-table, that is, need to add pagination only if the number of records is > say 5.

The reason is when the pagination is included in the data table, it occupies the space of a row on screen. In maximum cases, the number of rows would be 5 only. So, the intent is to save the screen space for these majority cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Say you've got this `dataTable` (from the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf)):**

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}"  
             paginator="true" rows="10"  
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
```

**You could turn the paginator conditionally off like this:**

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}"  
             paginator="#{tableBean.exceedsFive}" rows="10"  
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
```

The bean:

```
public boolean isExceedsFive() {
    return cars.size() > 5;
}
```

Notice the reference with EL in `paginator=""`.

Comment: Thanks :) It is so straightforward some how did not click. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome Shikha. Sometimes you're just searching for the hard way, happens to me too :)

Answer (score 16):

According to primefaces' documentation:

set dataTable paginator like this

```
 paginator="true" rows="5" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
```

- the paginator will be visible only if there are more than 5 records in the table.

Comment: +1 According to documentation you're right. Accepting this as the best answer is up to OP, which seems about right.

Comment: For sure this answer should be the first on the list.

Comment: It looks like this has been changed to `[alwaysShowPaginator]="false"` https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable